# CSS div border radius around image

Tags: css, html, border

i hope someone can answer this question because my client wants this and right now i dont know how to build this in css.

[image]

Does anyone know how to build something like this ?
It should be something like if you align your image to the right your text will align nicely with the image.

Here what i want to do is to build a div make a border around all the text that has been typed and then align it with the image. how could i do this?

After the help of Pete.

Problem here is the

```
box-shadow
```

Also the box needs to be transparant later in the stage.
This is my result right now http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/cu59r/.

Edit : Thank you for all the answers and support to help me solve this css issue.

The following thing it should happen is :

1. See the picture.
2. See the jsfiddle link i posted.
3. The content with the border needs a box-shadow, a border radius and a gradient.
4. This needs to be dynamic.

And again thank you community for helping me means alot to me.

Comment: Hi Wesley, welcome to SO.  Usually questions here are single-question-single-answer, I don't know if you'll get a very good response with a generic "how do I".  People like to see you've put in some effort ;)  But anyhow, you're on the right track with `border-radius`, maybe show us what you've tried and ask a specific question we can answer.

Comment: The rounding part can be done with border-radius, this link will show you more http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Comment: Hello Steve, Right now i have no clue and really desperate about it. Thats why i'm searching for an answer here.
Some idea's would be really good aswell or tips.

So i have a paragraph around it and i did a border 1px solid around it to see where it ends and it doesn't end till the part where image is aligned.

Comment: Is the image going to change size, ie is it dynamic or will it always be the same?

Comment: It is dynamic. The text and image will be generated through wordpress.

Comment: @WesleyCheung I have updated my answer to explain why what you are after is not possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with the use of a couple of images you should be able to create what you want

**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="imageHolder"><div class="inner"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" /></div></div>
    <!--put text here-->
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#wrapper {width:400px; border-radius:10px; border-top-right-radius:0px; background-color:#7ab37a; overflow:auto; padding:15px;}
#imageHolder {float:right; margin:-15px -15px 0 0; background:#ffffff url(http://i.imgur.com/gMIy72D.gif) left top no-repeat;}
#imageHolder .inner {background:url(http://i.imgur.com/RLBbLYV.gif) right bottom no-repeat; padding:10px 10px 20px 20px;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/cu59r/)

**Update**

With all your edits as to what you now want (instead of the simple l-shape in your original question).  This is not possible for the following reason

The text has to have a background colour which means that you need the background colour on the main wrapper so that it will make the l-shape.  This means the only way to get the desired effect of the rounded corners for the image is to place another background over the wrapper background (meaning you cannot have anything transparent otherwise the wrapper background-color will just show through)

The best you can hope for is to tell the client, if they want that shape, they will have to keep the images to an exact size and their text to a specific length and then you can use a simple background image

Comment: Wow this looks really promising. I will try implement this. If it succeeds i will approve this answer and this should answered my question thankyou!.

Comment: Hello Pete, so this is currently the issue http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/cu59r/ when i turn on the box shadow it also shadows the image.

Comment: Hi yeah, you never said anything about shadows and this isn't possible for a dynamic image that needs to be on a gradient background

Comment: Thank you pete for answering my question.
In the beginning i though after achieving the basics i could have solve the rest but it seems it was not possible, thats why i made some extra edits to see if the people could help me achieve the final goal.

But now i know that it is not possible i will inform my client. 
Thank you very much once again.

Answer (score 1):

I think there isn't a easy way to style your text-box like this.

My suggestion: designs the box with Photoshop and then add it as a background image in two different divs (the text box should have a transparent background where the image should be). After this you position the divs in the right way, if necessary with a wrapper div.

disadvantages: not responsive, static, and so on

Comment: Hello skull3r7, thank you for the suggestion.
The problem i have is that it needs to be dynamic. It does not matter if its responsive for this project. 
The reason that it needs to be dynamic is that the text and image will be generated through wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply float the image and it will look like this: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/wd/images/chapter3/text_wrap_final.gif

Just add

```
float: right/left;
margin: 0;
```

See if that works.

Comment: Hello, that is what i have but now comes the difficult part.
The text needs to have a border radius around it. the image needs to stay out of the border. Also this has to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

see this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MKgtp/) . Is this what you are expecting.

```
<figure style="float:right;">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question in my opinion :)

My short answer would be - yes, it's possible - see [Pete's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17104950/1144057). I understand the difficulty of the situation and also I understand the fact that this kind of solution lacks flexibility because it combines css `border-radius` and an image - so => a) it will look weird in IE8 and below and b) it will look weird if we change some css :)

My own answer would be to use css only to do that, but the main issue will be unsolved, the corners close to the image will not be rounded by any means in css that I'm aware of.

Consider looking at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/m6cpb/1/

I would prefer my variant because it's a bit *more flexible* - if there is a need of change - only css will change, no need of re-making any images of another color or of a different radius... no images needed at all :) Although you will need to style the images floated to the left differently and those - in the middle of the text as well.

Answer (score 0):

Skull3r7 had a good idea with `background-image`s. In addition, it is possible to use two divs with (dynamic) text and one other with the 'top border'.

- Layer one contains the text as 'placeholder' and 'bottom border',
- Layer two contains the 'top border image' (covers the top of Layer one)
- Layer three contains the visible text.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Stocki/K6HwQ/)

However, it is easier to implement Pete's solution, but I hope this example can help too. :)

Answer (score 0):

A further alternative to those suggested, given the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150" />
    <p><!-- text excised for brevity --></p>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.imgContainer {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
    border-radius: 1em;
}

.imgContainer img {
    float: right;
    margin: -1px -1px 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

.imgContainer p {
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 0.5em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QZ4yE/1/).

This should allow any size image to be used (so long as it fits within the container element, of course), and be responsive, and adaptable to changed sizes.

Unfortunately, though, I can't think of a way to provide the curve on the borders of the `img` itself. On the plus-side, it avoids needlessly wrapping and re-wrapping elements, so the HTML itself could, and *should*, stay pretty lean.